# How to include both for loop initial declarations and gnu extensions?

Tags: c, gcc, string.h

I have this code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char numbers[5] = "12345";

int main(){
  memrchr(numbers,'2',5);
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    printf("%d",i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

It uses for loop inital declarations (`for(int i`) and gnu extensions (`memrchr`).

I am using the compiler `gcc`

The problem is that it doesn't seem to let both go through. I can either do

```
gcc program.c -o program
```

Which complains about the for loops, or I can do

```
gcc -std=gnu11 program.c -o program
```

Which complains about `memrchr` being undefined. (or rather it complains about the implicit declaration of the function)

How do I do both? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the `_GNU_SOURCE` feature-test macro *before any library #include*. A convenient way to do that is to put it in your command line:

```
gcc -std=c11 -D_GNU_SOURCE program.c -o program
```

Or you could put the #define at the very top of every file which needs it. (Putting them in the source file is probably better, but I've gotten into the habit of putting them in my Makefiles. YMMV.)

You can see the needed feature-test macros in the manpage for every C library function. For example, `man memrchr` includes:

> Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):
>
> ```
>   memrchr(), rawmemchr(): _GNU_SOURCE
> ```

As that says, `man feature_test_macros` will tell you more.

Comment: Thank you, could you elaborate? Is there a webpage about it that I missed?

Comment: You can read manpages on the web, but it's usually more convenient to read them on your own machine.

Comment: @shelvacu: Typing `man memrchr` should show you the man page for the `memchr` function.